# Error in Tensorflow when run "mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to download and import MNIST data according to the Tensorflow tutorial using following commands in Ubuntu:

```
import tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist.input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

But, I get the below error when I run the second command:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Could you please advise me how I can fix this error? I need detailed instruction to run these commands. Do I need to run Python or import Tensorflow before running these commands?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Haha, yes you need to run those commands in Python. Were you running them on the sh command line? I admit the tensorflow MNIST tutorial does not explicitly state you need to run Python.

Try this:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 24 2015, 00:41:19) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
>>> mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
```

Comment: This is what I got when ran those commands:                     mehsad@mehsad-VirtualBox:/media/mehsad/extra/TensorFlow/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named examples.tutorials.mnist
>>> import input_data

Comment: >>> mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "input_data.py", line 198, in read_data_sets
    local_file = maybe_download(TRAIN_IMAGES, train_dir)
  File "input_data.py", line 35, in maybe_download
    if not tf.gfile.Exists(work_directory):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gfile'

Comment: It seems the fist command works when I use:>>> import input_data  , but second one generates another error like above.

Comment: It works fine for me. It will create a directory called 'MNIST_data' in whatever local directory you are running python in so make sure you have permissions to create a directory. Otherwise check your tensorflow installation.

Comment: I cannot find the MNIST_data. I can create folder on that directory, so I have the permission.  I have already ran and built a sample "object recognition" project with Tensorflow. Therefore my TensorFlow installation should be fine.

Comment: This error is unsolved yet. I have installed the TensorFlow at an extra drive which I created in Ubuntu. Is it possible this causes the above errors?

Comment: Yes, the error looks like wherever you are running Python from isn't the same environment where tensorflow is installed since it can't file the module attribute for gfile. Maybe because of the way you are using VirtualBox...but that is outside of my area of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to put '#!/usr/bin/python' :)